# solidity mapping does not seem to be working

Tags: solidity

I have this solidity code

```
contract Starting { //pragma solidity ^0.6.12

    struct itemStatus {
        bool created;
    }
    mapping (bytes => itemStatus) public item;
    
    bool[] public boolArray;    

    function start(bytes memory itemId) public {
        boolArray.push(item[itemId].created);
        if (item[itemId].created) {
            boolArray.push(item[itemId].created);
        } else {
            item[itemId] = itemStatus(true);
            boolArray.push(item[itemId].created);
        }
    }

    function getBoolArray() public view returns (bool[] memory) {
        return boolArray;
    }

}
```

frontend javascript code is

```
  toStart: function () {
    let Instance;
    App.contracts.Starting.deployed().then(function (instance) {
      Instance = instance;
      return Instance.start(itemId);
    }).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  },

  getArray: function () {
    let Instance;
    App.contracts.Starting.deployed().then(function (instance) {
      Instance = instance;
      return Instance.getBoolArray.call();
    }).then(function (array) {
      console.log(array);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  },
```

The first time I call 'toStart' and then 'getArray', I would expect itemId 1 [false, true] and the second time with the same itemId 1 [false, true, true, true] and third time with a different itemId 2 [false, true, true, true, false, true]. However, the actual result is [false, true, true, true, true, true]. It seems item[itemId] = itemStatus(true) has set all 'created' to true regardless of itemId. But if I use itemId 100 and 200, I get the expected result. Why is it so? How to change the code to get the expected result? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your code with remix and it works as expected. Are you really sure you used a different itemId?

Comment: @Ismael, you are right that it works as expected in remix. However, if I use Ganache with frontend and try itemId 1 and 2, I don't get the expected result. But if I try itemId 100 and 200, I get the expected result. Do you know what is the reason? Thanks

Comment: I'm 100% sure the error is in the frontend (to confirm that you can add to the contracts an event logging itemId). How do you make the calls in the frontend? What's the `itemId` scope?